# How do you call a JS function that is associated with a specific element in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Using the latest packages:js, how do I call a JS function that is associated with a specific html element/web component in Dart?

Example: In a third party framework known as OnsenUI, I am able to create an alert dialog by putting

```
<ons-alertdialog id='blah'>
  Test
</ons-alertdialog>
```

in the html.  Furthermore I am able to access this alertdialog's methods provided by OnsenUI via of document.querySelect('blah').show({options}); or
document.querySelect('blah').hide({options}) in javascript. So my question is what do I have to do to be able to access the show/hide method in Dart?

Here is their code in javascript:
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/core/src/elements/ons-alert-dialog/index.js

Here is their directive in angular2 with typescript:
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/bindings/angular2/src/directives/ons-alert-dialog.ts

My ultimate goal is to mimic what they have done in angular2 with typescript but using angular2 dart.  However, I am not sure how to implement below using Dart as I don't think directly calling this._onsAlertDialog.show() would work without using dart:js context.

```
/**
   * @method show
   * @signature show()
   * @return Promise<any>
   */
  show() {
    return this._onsAlertDialog.show();
  }

  /**
   * @method hide
   * @signature hide()
   * @return Promise<any>
   */
  hide() {
    return this._onsAlertDialog.hide();
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with using context?  The only approach I am aware of that will work would leverage the context object.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [JS pacakage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) you can create Dart classes that mirror the JavaScript API with annotations. For example:

```
@JS('google.maps')
library maps;

@JS()
class Map {
  external Map(Location location);
  external Location getLocation();
}
```

Now if you write Dart:

```
var l = getLocation();
var m = new Map(l);
```

it will be equivilent to JavaScript:

```
var l = google.maps.getLocation();
new google.maps.Map(l);
```

You'd need to create these classes over their API or use the context objects.